# How to get internal eslint plugins without the eslint-plugin-* prefix to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I have finished making an internal eslint plugin, but unfortunately our company requires us to prefix all of our internal npm packages with companyName-. This is causing issues with eslint looking for packages with eslint-plugin- prefix since my package is prefixed with companyName-*.

in my .eslintrc I have

```
"plugins": [
  "react",
  "babel",
  "lodash",
  "companyName-eslint-plugin-projectName"
],
```

eslint appends `eslint-plugin` to `companyName-eslint-plugin-teamName` and tries to look for `eslint-plugin-companyName-eslint-plugin-teamName`

is there anyway to bypass this in .eslintrc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out myself. You could set up an npm scope with your company name, and then publish the plugin under that scope: @companyName/eslint-plugin-something.